Output cells reset to scrolling when something is added to it
Jupyter version 7.2.2.
The context menu offers an option "Disable scrolling for outputs", and the grey sidebar has an option "Expand output", but neither of them persists: as soon as a line is added to the output it resets to scrolling.
I seem to remember this was not happening in older versions. Is it a bug? Can anything be done about it?
EDIT: This does not happen immediately. It starts happening when the output is approximately 50(?) lines.

Per this github issue, this is a known problem and there are two things that might work:

Disabling the relevant plugin:


jupyter labextension disable @jupyter-notebook/notebook-extension:scroll-output


Or, go to "Setting" > "Settings Editor" > "Jupyter Notebook Notebook" and uncheck "Auto Scroll Outputs"
Note, the menu item "Settings Editor" is not available in the notebook view, only in the file browser

